# How to make a python script to work with Django

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

so I have a python script I'd like to integrate to work with python. No matter what I do I don't seem to get it right. Below are what I've managed to do successfully which is getting Django to accept picture upload and display them to the user.

[image]

https://replit.com/@Eddyah5/ImageConverterwithHTML#main.py

I'm now trying to get my python script in the link above to work in Django to let users upload pictures out of the list of supported formats, convert the picture to .ico of different sizes, and zip them for download by users. Please pardon me I'm very new to python/Django. What to do with the views.py, models.py as pertaining my code is in the link below?

https://replit.com/@Eddyah5/ImageConverterwithHTML#main.py

I'm very new to python and Django, so any help I will deeply appreciate.

Comment: your answer looks too much generic. Try to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from Django admin then look into Admin Actions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

If you want to do it from frontend then make an API and call you code from view.